# Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. Problem with gstreamer1.0-vaapi package

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dependencies

I am getting this error when I tried to update my system (Ubuntu 22.04) and getting this error message

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  gstreamer1.0-vaapi
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

I have tried some solutions suggested on the internet like installing the package manually and i got this message:
`sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-vaapi`

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gstreamer1.0-vaapi : Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 (>= 1.20.3) but 1.20.1-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and "libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0" also already installed.
I have also tried commands like `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` but I am getting the same error.

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 with a Nvidia GPU.

[Edit]:
Guys, this is not a duplicate of `https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages` I have tried the suggestions from there but I am still having this issue. Thank You.

Comment: no, I have tried it too. the same error is shown even when i try these suggested commands.

Comment: You haven't provided any clear messages, which usually provide clues, ie. the package I'd expect to see is `gstreamer1.0-vaapi | 1.20.1-1                      | jammy/universe          | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` which has a fix currently in *-proposed* but your messages don't include such detail, thus we're limited in how we can look up details for you.  Your message does show `libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 | 1.20.3-0ubuntu1         | jammy-proposed/universe   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` where the satisfy requirement is in *-proposed* ...

Comment: how do I provide that message to you? Is there a specific command you want me to run so that I can share the outcome here?

Comment: I have asked a new question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420969/how-to-force-packages-have-been-kept-back-to-be-installed-automatic . My problem started exactly as yours, and now it has become something as explained in my question. Can you verify that in your system too?

Comment: You can try to correct it with Synaptic... https://forum.ubuntu-nl.org/index.php?PHPSESSID=408mhn99rt9in1s74jt0ucv755&topic=110293.msg1068274#msg1068274

Comment: @yaa__ Please look at this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1421041/855322

Comment: Yes, everyone please look at that answer! There are two variations of correct answer there. First is to disable phased updates, and second is to synchronize phased updates if you want all boxes phasing at the same time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to force "packages \[that\] have been kept back" to be installed \[as\] "automatic"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420969/how-to-force-packages-that-have-been-kept-back-to-be-installed-as-automat)

Answer (score 4):

I am getting the exact same error while running updates. Something, I believe, is currently broken in the current build chain. I would suggest waiting a little bit and seeing if a new update to the package fixes the issue:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade gstreamer1.0-vaapi/jammy-updates
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Selected version '1.20.1-1ubuntu1' (Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates [amd64]) for 'gstreamer1.0-vaapi'
Selected version '1.20.3-0ubuntu1' (Ubuntu:22.04/jammy-updates [amd64]) for 'libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0' because of 'gstreamer1.0-vaapi'
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad : Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 (= 1.20.1-1ubuntu2) but 1.20.3-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

Comment: Thanks for making my post readable FedKad :) -- I appreciate it.

Comment: Can you try the same command once more? It seems to have been fixed now!

Comment: Same issue as before. Package being held back.

Comment: Thanks, I will wait and see if new update fixes this issue or not.

Comment: @HCEarwicker The problem has become worse. And I have asked a new question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420969/how-to-force-packages-have-been-kept-back-to-be-installed-automatic . Can you verify that?

Comment: Everyone go check out @FedKad question and the two answers there. Both answers are correct for different use cases. The problem is not actually a bug, this is all part of a design decision (feature) made in Ubuntu called Phased Updates. You can disable it so everything behaves as older versions of Ubuntu did, or you can set the phasing to be synchronized on all computers you're running. Or you can understand what this feature is, and just leave it as is.